# Coordinates of pyramid

Tags: java, graphics, nested-loops

Alright, now it is a little clearer. My problem is the integer i. How come it does now subtract 1 from i each time the first for-loop is iterated.

> import acm.graphics.*;
>   import acm.util.*;
>   import acm.program.*;

public class Pyramid extends GraphicsProgram {

```
public void run() {
    pyramid();
}

private GRect brick() {
    GRect brick = new GRect(30,12);
    return brick;
}

private void pyramid() {
    int xCoord = 0;
    int yCoord = getHeight()-BRICK_HEIGHT;
    for (int k = 0; k<=12;k++) {
        i--;
        for (i=12; i>=1;i--) {
            add(brick(),xCoord,yCoord);
            xCoord += BRICK_WIDTH;
    }
    yCoord -= BRICK_HEIGHT;
    xCoord = 0;
    }
}

private int i;
private static final int BRICK_WIDTH = 30;
private static final int BRICK_HEIGHT = 12;
private static final int BRICKS_IN_BASE = 12;
```

}

Comment: Could you clarify this? _" Why is my row nummer two in extent of my first row?"_

Comment: Why are `Y_COORDINATE` and `i` **static** fields? Why are they fields at all? Why is `Y_COORDINATE` in all uppercase, which usually indicate a constant? What is the purpose of `i--;` after the for-loop? There is no `x-coordinate` in the code, so what are you talking about?

Comment: @trobbins When you run the program, row number two(Counting from bottom) begins almost at the x-coordinate equivalent to where the first row ends.

Comment: @Andreas What is was trying to do with the i--; was to get the for-loop to execute one time fewer for each time that it is run. Do you understand? Because for each row there has to be one brick fewer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep it simple. No class variables except static finals, no fields. You can do it all in a single method; there's hardly a good reason for using additional methods.

```
private void pyramid(){
    int xBase = 0;
    int yCoord = getHeight() - BRICK_HEIGHT;
    // 12 rows of decreasing length: 12, 11,... 1
    for( int rowlen = 12; rowlen >= 1; --rowlen ){
        // lay the bricks - calculate x-coordinate
        for( int iBrick = 0; iBrick < rowlen; ++iBrick ){
            add( brick(), xBase + iBrick*BRICK_WIDTH, yCoord );
        }
        // indent for next row
        xBase += 15;
        // advance vertically
        yCoord -= BRICK_HEIGHT;
    }
```